# Route certain websites over 4G instead of DSL

Tags: routing

We have a client with rubbish DSL (3Mbps). Most websites & email are fine working over this slow connection but we have 2-3 websites that we need to load faster & want to route those websites over 4G, while keeping everything else on the ADSL connection.

Has anyone had any experience doing this & what you you recommend? Was hoping the Unfi stuff could do something like this but I'm not even sure where to look - https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi .. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you know what you're asking about. This is confusing. What problem are you looking to solve?

Comment: I'd look at Mikrotik but we need way more detail for any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use a cable modem with like a cellular stick on 4GLTE network, more commonly named a turbohub ? ask your **ISP**/**Broadband provider** please, as they are the only one that can sell you the device with a integrated LTE data plan.

When you will have the stick, then just use another router behind that link to route there for those websites (***route add ip mask 255.255.255.255 ip_of_this_router***), or use a dual WAN router to force the route directly in the router.

A exemple of the product I mean;

https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/4g-broadband-router-faqs/
https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Mobile-Internet-Devices-listing
...

Does I recommand it ? No, as you can bust your cellular data's plan. If your customer is ready to pay for that speed, then go ahead, as I understand your need, as some of my customers are on bad ADSL and LTE network's speedtest can be 10x more than the ADSL's one.